# Multiple client with single server program in c (TCP)

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp

I wrote server program using select(). In this program I can able to connect multiple clients. But this server is talking only to the latest client. I cannot find the problem. Please help me out. For client program, I'm using telnet command (telnet 192.168.100.143 8181).

**SERVER.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define SERVER_IP       "192.168.100.143"
#define CLIENT_IP       "192.168.100.5"
#define PORT            8181

#define BUF_LEN         256

fd_set read_fd;
int32_t server_id, client_id, fdmax, ret, client_no;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;

int main()
{
        int32_t opt=1;
        socklen_t len;
        char IP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN],buffer[BUF_LEN];

        if((server_id=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1) {
        perror("Unable to create Server ocket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if( setsockopt(server_id, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0 ) {
                perror("setsockopt error...");
                exit(-1);
        }

        memset((char *) &server,0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(PORT);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_IP , &server.sin_addr);
    bzero(&server.sin_zero,8);

    if((bind(server_id,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)))==-1) {
        perror("Unable to bind the server address...");
        exit(-1);
    }

    listen(server_id,5);
    printf("\nWaiting for connection\n");

        FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
    FD_SET(server_id,&read_fd);

    fdmax=server_id;

        while(1){

                printf("%d\n",__LINE__);
                printf("fdmax = %d \n",fdmax);
                if((select(fdmax+1,&read_fd,NULL,NULL,NULL)) <0) {
                        perror("Select\n");
                        return -1;
                }
                printf("%d\n",__LINE__);

                if(FD_ISSET(server_id,&read_fd)) {
                        if((client_id=accept(server_id,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&len))==-1) {
                        perror("Cannot accept the client...");
                        exit(-1);
                        }
                        printf("New client  %d connectd  \n",client_id);
                        FD_SET(client_id, &read_fd);
                        fdmax = client_id;
                } else {
                        for(client_no = server_id+1; client_no <=fdmax; client_no++) {
                                if(FD_ISSET(client_no, &read_fd)) {
                                        printf("%d\n",__LINE__);
                                        ret = recv(client_no, buffer, BUF_LEN, 0);
                                        if(ret == 0) {
                                                printf("client  %d disconnectd  \n",client_no);
                                                FD_CLR(client_no, &read_fd);
                                                close(client_no);
                                                break;
                                        } else {
                                                printf("Received from client %d = %s \n",client_no,buffer);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        close(client_id);
        close(server_id);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call FD_SET on all file descriptors(including listener fd) in every iteration of `while(1)`.

In your code the `server_id` is not set inside `while(1)` loop. And as such, new socket connections and data on them  are not notified once the first client was connected and sent in data.'

```
while(1)
{
   FD_SET(server_id,&read_fd); //This should work.
...
}
```